# android - How to show dialog after activity finishes

Tags: android

Say we have two activities, Activity1 and Activity2.

In Activity1's onClick() method, we have a call to start Activity 2 if a certain button is pressed:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
Activity1.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

After finish() is called in Activity2, and Activity1 is resumed, I need a dialog to show in Activity1, as soon as it is resumed.

Before, I simply called showDialog(id) in the same block of Activity1's onClick() method:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
     if(v == addHole){
     //...
     Intent myIntent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
     Activity1.this.startActivity(myIntent);
     showDialog(END_DIALOG_ID);
     }
}
```

The issue is, after Activity1 resumes, the dialog corresponding to END_DIALOG_ID is not visible, but the screen is darkened and unresponsive (as if the dialog were present), until the back key is pressed.

I have tried putting the showDialog() call in Activity1's onResume() and onRestart() methods, but these both crash the program.

I have also tried creating an AsyncTask method in Activity2, with the showDialog() call in its onPostExecute(), but the dialog is not visible in Activity2.

```
private class ShowDialogTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> {
    /** The system calls this to perform work in a worker thread and
     * delivers it the parameters given to AsyncTask.execute() */
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... id) {
        //do nothing
        return END_DIALOG_ID;
    }

    /** The system calls this to perform work in the UI thread and delivers
     * the result from doInBackground() */
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer id) {
        super.onPostExecute(id);
        showDialog(id);

    }
}
```

I am now trying to implement this by calling

```
Activity1.this.startActivityForResult(myIntent, END_DIALOG_REQUEST);
```

with corresponding setResult() and onActivityResult() methods from Activity1, but it seems that there should be a better practice for implementing this. All I need is to have a dialog shown upon Activity2 finishing.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: I was going to suggest startActivityForResult and onActivityResult, but you seem to have discovered it on your own.  To me, that's the most straightforward way to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like you suggest, call `startActivityForResult` when starting `Activity2`. Then, override `onActivityResult` and check for `RESULT_OK`, and show your dialog box then. That's a perfectly acceptable practice for doing what you're looking to do.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be the best answer, as overriding `onResume()` causes the dialog to be shown the first time Activity1 is started, and `onRestart()` causes the dialog to be shown if the application loses focus. Using `startActivityForResult` seems to be better at only showing the dialog when Activity2 finishes (or is cancelled via the BACK key). Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome. One other thing to keep in mind, is that `onResume()` will be called if the user navigates to another app (phone, messaging, whatever), and then back to your activity.

Comment: Hmm, yes. That's a good point. But I think `startActivityForResult` will work better, as I only want the dialog to show after Activity2 finishes and Activity1 comes into focus. The dialog is for getting a timestamp, and it needs to be at the time of the transition of Activity2 back into Activity1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use onResume method (if u'r not looking anything from activity2)

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Using the showDialog() in onResume() also causes the dialog to be shown when Activity1 is first created.

Comment: However, using onRestart instead of onResume appears to function as desired. I forgot to call `super.onRestart()` when I tried that before. What cases might I have to worry about onRestart() being called other than after Activity2 finishes?

Comment: You need to make sure every variable u'r gonna use in `onRestart()` have already been initiated/re-initiated or it will throw `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 0):

I have to return to the root activity - MainActivity, potentially closing several activities, and then show dialog. So I have chosen alternative way.

```
MyDialog {
    public static synchronized void planToShowDialog(String info) {
        if (info != null) {
            saveInfoToPreferences(info);
        }
    }

    public static synchronized void showDialogIfNecessary(Context context) {
        String info = readInfoFromPreferences(); 
        if (info != null) {
            saveInfoToPreferences(null); // Show dialog once for given info.
            new MyDialog(context, info).show();
        }
    }

    private static String readInfoFromPreferences() {
        //...
    }

    private static void saveInfoToPreferences(String info) {
        //...
    }
}
```

I call MyDialog.showDialogIfNecessary() from MainActivity.onPostResume() method.