# Can we show the dialog after finish the Activity?

Tags: android, dialog

I have tried this but dialog box is dismiss when Activity finish because the dialog takes an context of an Activity.Is there any way for it?

Comment: Why you want to show dialog after finishing activity?and the answer of your question is no.

Comment: NO there is no way. Also in order to avoid the WindowLeakException I will check the Activity isFinishing() flag before showing the dialog

Comment: within same activity context you can not show.

Comment: To those who are wondering why someone might wanna show a dialog without an activity a simple use case is an initialization error message.

Answer (score 3):

You can. Create a separate activity to show your dialog box. Define your dialog activity in the manifest as following:

```
<activity android:name=".DialogActivity"     
         android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"                                 
        android:excludeFromRecents="true" android:taskAffinity=""
        android:launchMode="singleInstance">
</activity>
```

Define your dialog box or whatever you want to show in this activity. Start this DialogActivity when you finish your activity.

Comment: This fit my needs perfectly. Since the question is closed you should add this answer to http://stackoverflow.com/q/11143033/262789, which is a similar question.

Answer (score 1):

A Fragments life is stuck to the Activity it is attached to, so that is the expected behavior. A way to get around that is to, say, have Activity B return something to Activity A through `startActivityForResult`. This way the Dialog pops up immediately after Activity B finishes, but maintains its life through Activity A, which would not be destroyed at that point in time.

Answer (score 0):

When activity finishes you cannot show the dialog with its reference. Since activity is not present in activity stack. instead you can show the dialog by giving the reference of previous activity.

Or you can use `startActivityForResult` and show the dialog in it.

Answer (score -4):

You can try do it from, application context

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
//Your dialog setup here

builder.show();
```

Comment: the question is "can we show ??" not how to show ?? -1

Comment: This code can be called from activity

Comment: Always getting: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application. Probably this way is not possible

Comment: Yes, dialogs need a hosting activity to display, unfortunately.